# Rebooting an Azure VM within an ansible playbook

Tags: azure, ansible, azure-virtual-machine

I've an inventory that looks like this:

```
virtualmachines:
   hosts:
      Name-Of-My-Azure-VM-Here:
         ansible_host: 1.2.3.4
         ansible_port: 22
      Name-Of-My-Other-Azure-VM-Here:
         ansible_host: 2.3.4.5
         ansible_port: 22
```

I'm trying to reboot the machine when I'm done with the setup. The built in reboot command throws an error:

> Reboot command failed. Error was: 'Failed to set wall message, ignoring: Interactive authentication required.\r\nFailed to call ScheduleShutdown in logind, no action will be taken: Interactive authentication required., Shared connection to 1.2.3.4 closed

... so I'm attempting to use the shell command which does work if I launch it locally:

```
az vm restart --resource-group "My-RG-Name" --name <my VM name here>
```

Of course, this command needs to execute on the machine that is executing the playbook, not the remote. Let's say my playbook looks like this attempt:

```
# This part run on N remote hosts
- name: Setup Middleware
  hosts: virtualmachines
  tasks:
    - name: Edit the config file to tell the software its own name
      ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
         path: /home/some/file.txt
         regexp: '^MyOwnName='
         line: MyOwnName="{{ inventory_hostname }}"  # in this portion of the playbook {{inventory_hostname}} resolves to 'Name-Of-My-VM-Here'

# This part run locally
- name: Restart Azure VM locally using Azure CLI
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Restart Azure VM
      command: az vm restart --resource-group "My-RG-Name" --name ... # this needs to be 'Name-Of-My-VM-here' but I don't know how to get it - in this portion of the playbook {{inventory_hostname}} resolves to 'localhost'
```

I'm stuck on the part where I need to tell `az` the name(s) of the machine(s) to reboot.
In the "remote part" of the playbook this can easily come from the inventory file and I would ordinarily access it with `{{ inventory_hostname }}` in that "remote part" of the playbook..

But how can I run a command in a "host: local" section, that uses whatever `{{ inventory_hostname }}` value was active in the remote part of the playbook?

Alternatively if there is a way to get the builtin reboot command to work, that would seem to be the simplest option..

Comment: You should use ansible, the ansible way. Which is to setup ssh connection and reboot from the machine

Comment: That is done already; running the playbook asks me for the passphrase for the SSH key, it does a boatload of stuff I haven't replicated here in the interest of brevity, but I haven't been able to find a way to make `ansible.builtin.reboot:` reboot an azure vm; it just gives the error noted in the question

Comment: use a shell or command: `sudo shutdown -r now`

Comment: Hmm.. it seems a bit awkward because it prompts me to enter the SSH key passphrase again, then hangs the playbook execution

Comment: pass in "--ask-become-pass" flag to supply password or. just add "become: true" to ansible task

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this. Like mentioned in the comments. This can also be done this way.

Remember to add `**become: true**`

```
- name: Reboot the server
  become: true
  ansible.builtin.shell: shutdown -r now

- name: Reboot with Command
  become: true
  command: shutdown -r now

- name: Reboot with BuiltIn
  reboot:
```

---> from Ansible Docs

```
- name: Unconditionally reboot the machine with all defaults
  ansible.builtin.reboot:

- name: Reboot a slow machine that might have lots of updates to apply
  ansible.builtin.reboot:
    reboot_timeout: 3600

- name: Reboot a machine with shutdown command in unusual place
  ansible.builtin.reboot:
    search_paths:
     - '/lib/molly-guard'

- name: Reboot machine using a custom reboot command
  ansible.builtin.reboot:
    reboot_command: launchctl reboot userspace
    boot_time_command: uptime | cut -d ' ' -f 5

- name: Reboot machine and send a message
  ansible.builtin.reboot:
    msg: "Rebooting machine in 5 seconds"
```

Comment: Thanks! Note, none of the "from Ansible docs" examples, nor your "Reboot with Builtin" variant cites `become: true` and this appears to be required, at least for the VMs I have in Azure.. In essence that was probably the secret sauce I was missing in my particular case, though I was certain I'd tried it..

Comment: reboot is a SUDO operation. So you would need `become: true` in it.

Answer (score 1):

I was convinced that I'd tried adding `become: true` to my original attempt to reboot the machine using the built-in `reboot:` command, but perhaps not. Using the following in the playbook worked to reboot the machine:

```
    - name: Reboot (re-prompt for the SSH key passphrase means server is done rebooting)
      become: true
      ansible.builtin.reboot:
```